# Trying to make a filter taxonomy menu with multiple vocabularies

Tags: 7, commerce, taxonomy-terms

I'm currently having trouble getting a taxonomy menu to act as a product display filter.  Actually I think I may need multiple menus as my products need to be filtered by: category, price, and color. I can do the filters separate, but they need to stay active together such as a filter with a category of 'all' and a price of 0 to 99 and color of red.  I am hoping to get this working somehow with views rather than recoding, but that is an option as well.  I'm still a little new to Drupal, and this is my first Drupal commerce kickstart site.  Using Drupal 7 and commerce kickstart 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you mean "taxonomy vocabularies" when you say "taxonomy menu". Because actual menus like the navigation are not really suitable for this task.

Scince you are using Commerce Kickstart, you can simply use multiple Search Blocks as Filters and join their results. The View "Display Products" that comes with Commerce Kickstart by default actually has already a Block with the "Price" Filter on it.

I am assuming that your product display already has fields for the Term references to your taxonomy vocabulary. Also assuming you have not changed these settings yet, go to `Administration » Configuration » Search and metadata » Search API » Product display » Fields` and select the fields of your product that you want to filter for. Then reindex them and go to `Administration » Configuration » Search and metadata » Search API » Product display » Facets`, select your new fields and edit their display (e.g. checkboxes for color and ranges for price). Make sure you select "AND" as an operator if you want to have the products that match every filter.

Once you have that, go to `Administration » Structure » Blocks` and put the newly created blocks on the sites you need them on (e.g. /products)

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I'm using Drupal 7 with commerce kickstart 1.0

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you really try to achive. Can you maybe show me some wireframes or explain in other words what you you want your page to look like?

Comment: Okay I switched to CK2 and filters are now working!  Thanks!